# Dynamic Menus Paper Item

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am currently  using paper dropdown menu, paper listbox  and paper item web components to try and create a list. The code is the following:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Assigned" vertical-align>
 <paper-listbox attr-for-selected="id" class="dropdown-content" fallback-selection="default" selected="{{assignedFilter}}">
  <paper-item id="default">Select Configs</paper-item>
  <paper-item id="displayAssignedConfigs">TRUE</paper-item>
  <paper-item id="displayAllConfigs">ALL</paper-item>
 </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

In this example, there are 3 paper items that have static text. I would like the number of items in the list and the text in these items to be generated dynamically based on the response from an Ajax request I am making.

Any ideas or devs that have done this kind of thing before would be a great help. I am programming using Polymer 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dom-repeat` helper element:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Assigned" vertical-align>
  <paper-listbox attr-for-selected="id" class="dropdown-content" fallback-selection="default" selected="{{assignedFilter}}">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{ajaxResponse}}">        
      <paper-item id="{{item.id}}">{{item.label}}</paper-item>
    </template>
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

The above assuming that your ajax returns a response in the form of:

```
[
  {id: "default", label: "Select Configs"},
  {id: "displayAssignedConfigs", label: "TRUE"},
  {id: "displayAllConfigs", label: "ALL"},
  ...
]
```

Comment: the ajax response will contain different data than has been shown here but I plan on reading up on dom-repeat and dom-if to try and get this implemented in the way I would like - thanks!